# gdb failed with sigsev, don't know why?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

In my project, I build three applications, in my Linux host machine.

Output binaries are,
    main_process
    update_data
    db_process

**Questions:**

- gdb handles only one executables to debug at one time?
- All these three executables can't be run once in gdb?

When I run,

gdb ./main_process

Error message from gdb:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/iir/bin/ 
warning: `/lib/ld-linux.so.2': Shared library architecture i386 is not compatible with target architecture i386:x86-64.
warning: `/lib/ld-linux.so.2': Shared library architecture i386 is not compatible with target architecture i386:x86-64.
Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7dda402 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7dda402 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x10074
```

EDIT: This question got downvotes, I want to mention here, the segfault caused because of running arm binaries in GDB. I've noticed that its bug in our build system where it didn't build actually for the arm arch instead x86.

Comment: You need to re-compile your code with debugging information turned on (-g option in gcc for example) - then you'll be able to see where your code is crashing.

Comment: looks like an architecture mismatch to me (32 vs 64 bit), not a `gdb` problem. Are you trying to cross-compile? What happens if you run `./main_process` without `gdb`?

Comment: @yano yes I cross compiling for the arm target(32bit) in Linux host(64 bit)

Comment: from this printout it doesn't look like you're even using an x64 to ARM toolchain. i386 and i386x86_64 are both Intel/AMD architectures, not ARM. [Linaro](https://www.linaro.org/downloads/) makes x64 to ARM toolchains. If you already have one, doesn't look like you're pointed to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question got downvotes, I want to mention here, the segfault caused because of running arm binaries in host GDB.

I've noticed that its bug in our build system where it didn't build actually for the arm arch instead x86.

**Questions:**

gdb handles only one executables to debug at one time?
Answer: Yes and I can able to pass another executable in as an argument using run.

All these three executables can't be run once in gdb?
Answer: No.

Answer (score 1):

> Error message from gdb
>   `(gdb) r
>   Starting program: /home/iir/bin/`

The error message says that you are trying to *execute* `/home/iir/bin/` which appears to be a directory. It is very unlikely that this is the actual result you observed after running `gdb ./main_process`.

Conclusion: you are not telling us what you *actually* did and what you observe, and trying to guess what that might be is a waste of time.

Comment: @Employee Russian , it's my silly mistake, what I did is actually trying to debug the binaries which i cross compiled for arm. Later I find out that I am not using the binaries which I build for Linux host. Gdb failed because I was running incompatible executable. I haven't setup the gdb server in my target (arm) yet.